# SQL Subtract two columns on different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Customer, and Invoices,I have to list all the customers with their remaining credit. I'm trying to subtract the sum of the Invoice Amount column from the `CreditLimit` column to give me the remaining credit?

[image: Tables]

This is my query so far

```
DECLARE @CreditRemaining INT

SELECT 
   @CreditRemaining = (c.CreditLimit - SUM(i.Amount))
FROM 
     Customer c 
INNER JOIN 
     Invoices i on
     c.ID = i.customerId
```

Comment: why do you have a variable?

Comment: You are assigning the result to a variable, yet the variable can only hold *one* value. Presumably, your query return more values. Hence, the variable will only hold the last value selected (since you don't have an `order by`, which record is last is unpredictable). What is your intention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a derived table for the invoice amount `SUM()`, then `JOIN` back to Customer:

```
DECLARE @CreditRemaining INT

SELECT @CreditRemaining = (c.CreditLimit - TotalSpent)
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) TotalSpent, CustomerID
            FROM Invoices
            GROUP BY CustomerID) i ON i.CustomerID = c.ID
```

As others mentioned, this is assuming you are limiting your selection to one customer.

For all customers, just use a select:

```
SELECT C.Name, (c.CreditLimit - TotalSpent) CreditRemaining
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(Amount) TotalSpent, CustomerID
            FROM Invoices
            GROUP BY CustomerID) i ON i.CustomerID = c.ID
GROUP BY C.Name
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have to list all customers with their remaining credit, appologies

Comment: @F.OLeary NP, just use a select if that's the case.  Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks mate,is TotalSpent a variable?

Comment: @F.OLeary Nope, it's just what I named the `SUM(Amount)` column from the derived table.  The inner, derived table, will sum the invoice amount for each customer ID, THEN join back to the main customer table.

Comment: @F.OLeary I might get off track by saying more, but basically the issue with doing a straight join, without first calculating the sum, is that you would duplicate Customer records for each invoice amount.  Using the derived table, or subquery, creates a single `SUM(invoice.Amount)` for each customer before the join, which prevents that duplication.

Comment: Should the derived table be named with AS DerivedTable ??

Comment: @F.OLeary `AS` is optional for aliasing in SQL Server.  Currently the derived table is named `i`, but you could type `AS i` or whatever else you want to call it.  That is after the closing `)`.  Side note, the same applies for columns.  I aliased the inner sum `TotalSpent` without `AS`, for example. You can add `AS` in if you prefer to read it that way.

Comment: Thank you,I understand it now